# Daily I’m receiving a new table in the BigQuery, I want concatenate this new table data to the main table, dataset schema are same

Tags: google-bigquery

Daily I’m receiving a new table (example :tablename_20220811) in the BigQuery, I want concatenate this new table data to the main_table, dataset schema are same.

I tried using wild cards,I don’t know how to pull the daily loaded table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigQuery` [scheduled](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) queries with an interval (cron) in the schedule parameters :

Example with `gcloud` cli :

```bash
bq query \
  --use_legacy_sql=false \
  --destination_table=mydataset.desttable \
  --display_name='My Scheduled Query' \
  --schedule='every 24 hours' \
  --append_table=true \
  'SELECT
    1
   FROM
    mydataset.tablename_*
    where _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())'
```

In order to target on the expected table, I used a wildcard and a filter based on the table suffix. The table suffix should be equals to the current date as `STRING` with the following format `yyyymmdd`.

The cron plan to run the query every day.

You can also configure it directly with the Google Cloud console.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the right naming format for BigQuery to treat your tables as a single 'date-sharded table'.

You need to ensure that the daily tables

- have the same schema
- are in the same dataset
- have the same name apart from the `_yyyymmdd` suffix

You will know if this worked because only *one* table will appear (with an icon showing multiple tables, rather than the usual icon).

With this in hand, you can write queries like

```sql
    SELECT
        fieldA,
        fieldB,
      FROM
       `some_dataset.tablename_*`
     WHERE
        _table_suffix BETWEEN '20220101' AND '20221201'
```

This gives you some idea of what's possible:

- select from the full date-sharded table using backticks (essential!) and the wildcard syntax
- filter using the special `_table_suffix` meta-field